# Density of Mahout SparseMatrix

Tags: java, machine-learning, mahout, sparse-matrix

A short and simple question about Mahout's SparseMatrix class:

*Is there an easy (already available via Mahout) way to calculate the density of a sparse matrix?*

I ask this because I have a label propagation algorithm running, which is implemented using `SparseMatrix`. My program runs `out of memory`, and I think it is because `the density of the matrix` increases at a rate faster than I anticipated. I will have to write my own method to calculate the density if nothing is available, but, if an answer stops me from reinventing the wheel, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

`SparseMatrix.getNumNondefaultElements()` appears to return the number of non-empty rows and the number of non-empty entries, so you could calculate a pessimistic estimate by multiplying these two numbers.

Comment: The documentation of this method confused me a bit. It returns an int[2] containing [row, column] count. I was unable to find any further details. Does it mean it will return the number of rows and columns that are not entirely zero? If so, then multiplying them will not give me the density. But I will try it out on some small manually created matrices and check.

Comment: I assume by "density" of a matrix you mean the number of non-zero entries in the matrix.

As far as I understood the source code, `SparseMatrix.getNumNondefaultElements()` gives you the number of rows which are not entirely zero, and the number of non-zero entries in the "densest" column. 

So the product of both should give you an estimate which is greater or equal to the actual number of nonzero entries. I can't find a method that gives you the actual number of nonzeros.